# Replacing an AC power supply that is 2 volts higher than the original but has the same current rating

Tags: current, ac

I have an audio mixer that requires an AC 16 volt 1 amp external power adapter. I need to know if an 18 volt 1 amp AC external power adapter would work without damaging the audio mixer?

Comment: Sadly, Dan, I think this question is off-topic for ee.se, and may get closed. It appears to be about repairing electronics, which tends to be too specific for ee.se. Please look at the [help] for advice on how to ask questions which are likely to get answers.

Comment: canonical thread on the topic: [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/7036)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, but it's not guaranteed.  The mixer likely has a bridge rectifier followed by one or more linear voltage regulators (perhaps including a negative supply, hence the AC input).  Those rectifiers, the smoothing capacitors and the regulators probably have some safety margin on the voltage rating.  But without looking at a schematic or disassembling the device, you can't know for sure.

Comment: I have no idea what the target DC within the equipment is. I do have xlr output connectors that provide 48 volts phantom power. If I test the DC output power at these connectors and they test  at 48 volts, would that be a good indicator that this power supply would work?

Comment: No, that won't be much of an indicator.

It will almost certainly work for a while, the question is whether lifetime will be reduced (i.e. will some part of the power supply burn out after a while)

Comment: What would I look for, within the equipment to give me an indication that 18 volts AC is too much. such as components within the rectifier. EG: diodes that are getting warm at the rectifier. I assume the problem will expose itself at the conversion to DC. Thanks for your input!

Comment: If you're willing to open the case, try to trace and draw the schematic of the components at the front end.  Then check the voltage rating of any electrolytic capacitors involved & compare to the expected rectified voltage, taking into account the usual practice of derating.  Overheating will show itself on the linear regulator(s), though you might need to connect the mic or whatever to the XLR to draw current before you'd notice that.